# I want to return multiple objects using django def get_context_data

Tags: django

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kcl = self.request.user.kcal
    men_kcal = 13.8 * kcl.weight
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    if kcl.goal == 'diet':
        context['bmr'] = men_kcal - 500
    else:
        context['bmr'] = men_kcal + 500
    return context

    context['fixbmr'] = bmr * 2
```

I want to represent an object in the template.

`{{ bmr }}`
And
`{{ fixbmr }}`

I'd like to use.
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Right now your code is returning early so the `fixbmr` won't be available in your template. Secondly, you're not storing `bmr` in a variable so your `bmr * 2` wouldn't work either. Fixing both those issues will make your code work as intended

Comment: How should I modify it?

Comment: 'return context '   change   'copntext['fxibmr'] = bmr *2 ??

Comment: Extract `bmr` to its own variable and move `return context` below `context['fixbmr'`] = bmr * 2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kcl = self.request.user.kcal
    men_kcal = 13.8 * kcl.weight
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    if kcl.goal == 'diet':
        context['bmr'] = men_kcal - 500
    else:
        context['bmr'] = men_kcal + 500

    context['fixbmr'] = context['bmr'] * 2

    return context
```